# Using #ifdef in static libraries (C++, Eclipse CDT)

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, linker, microcontroller

i have a question regarding my project management in Eclipse CDT, programming in C++ and using GCC to compile. 
Lets say I have a driver library for microcontroller-type A (driverA.hpp) and a driver library for microcontroller-type B (driverB.hpp) (peripherals etc.). In both libraries the function interfaces are the same. Furthermore I have libraries for certain devices like device X which should be usable for both controller types (example: deviceX.hpp). In a project (projectY) using those things, I will add the corresponding driver library (driverA.hpp or driverB.hpp) and I want to add a compiler flag in order to name the controller type I want to use.

In deviceX.hpp, I want to make a distinction between the two types, so I thought of adding something likes this:

```
#ifdef CONTROLLER_A
  #include driverA.hpp
#elseif CONTROLLER_B
  #include driverB.hpp
#endif
```

This library will also be linked to projectY, in which I want to add a compiler flag like CONTROLLER_A and the library deviceX with the correct controller type will be linked.

BUT, I know, that does not work. That's why I'm asking you: what is the best (or: the common) way to do such library dependencies? Adding the deviceX libary as Source Location? Or is there another way?

Best Regards

Comment: I'd probably do this in the build-system.

Comment: Yes, thats probably the way, but I'm not proficient enough in the C++ build system in Eclipse to know how to do this and couldn't find a good answer on the net, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: I would simply avoid static libraries if at all possible -- which would also yield better binaries.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you would suggest adding the needed drivers directly to the Source Folder?

Comment: Investigate build configurations in your Eclipse help system.  I haven't used it in over a decade, but I recall they do supply UI for you to setup separate build configurations, such that the /DCONTROLLER_A macro definition will be supplied on the command line to the compiler.

Comment: If the function interfaces for the two device drivers are the same, then what actually differs between their headers?

Comment: The actual implementation is different for the two controller types. Or do I miss something important that outs me as a newby in the field? I just want to have reusable code in different locations that can be used for two different types of microcontrollers but has the same interface for upcoming projects

Comment: Well if I use the /DCONTROLLER_A macro, how can I apply it to the static library in the different folder? As far as I understood, the static library is compiled first, so my macro/symbol has no effect on it. Or can that be turned around?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to accomplish what you want but one thing to note is that if the drivers for both MCUs have the same interface (as per your question) then there would be absolutely no point in including different headers based on different MCU #defines. If you want the solution to be #define based you could for example do:

Header (some_driver.h):

```
// init.
void some_driver_init(struct init_params ip);

// start driver
void some_driver_start();
```

"Fake" implementaion (some_driver.c):

```
#if defined(ARM_CORTEX_M3)  
#include "some_driver_arm_m3.c"
#elif defined(TI_MSP430) 
#include "some_driver_msp430.c"
#elif defined(...)  
//... and so on...
#else  
#pragma warning "MCU NOT SUPPORTED!"
#endif
```

Then "real" implementation for each MCU:

some_driver_arm_m3.c

```
// init. M3 Cortex driver
void some_driver_init(struct init_params ip)
{
// actual M3 implementation goes here
}

// start M3 Cortex driver
void some_driver_start()
{
// actual M3 implementation goes here
}
```

some_driver_msp430.c

```
// init. MSP430 driver
void some_driver_init(struct init_params ip)
{
// actual MSP430 implementation goes here
}

// start MSP430 driver
void some_driver_start()
{
// actual MSP430 implementation goes here
}
```

... and so on.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Yes I understand your proposal and it looks quite promising and I will use it. The thing I don't understand yet, if it is possible to use this approach in a static library (.a file) which will be added by the linker by the -l command. That will be compiled automatically before my project and as far as I tried it does not respond (I guess that's the way it is) to my global symbols and defines. Is there a chance to pass a global symbol before compiling?

Comment: The ability to do this would depend on the specific compiler you plan on using. Most modern compilers do support this and I have actually used this method in the past to build an "agnostic" static library which can be passed to customers without divulging the source code.

Comment: As an example, in IAR's Embedded Workbench (a popular embedded compiler which I happen to have installed now) you could accomplish this by using "defined symbols" (under project options->compiler->preprocessor) to predefine the ARM_CORTEX_M3 symbol (or whatever symbol you might need) before compiling the lib.

Comment: Another way to do this is to #define ARM_CORTEX_M3 in a file named cortex_m3_defines.h and then force-include that file in your compilation as neede using "preinclude file" which will auto-include that header in all compilation units of your project (on IAR this is again under compiler->preprocessor->preinclude file).

Comment: Obviously these options are available from the command line as well in the form of compilation flags, to be used for integrating the compilation process with your build system (e.g. make) if you happen to use one.

Comment: If in your question you are referring to the possibility of doing this without recompiling the lib (your wording is not quite clear on this) then this is obviously impossible. You can either recompile the lib as needed on a per-MCU basis or have a directory filled with precompiled libs, one for each supported MCU, which can then be linked to your projects by the linker as needed.

Comment: No, I'm aware that I need to recompile the library. In Eclipse, there is the same option "defined symbols" under G++ Compiler -> Preprocessor. But that does not seem to have an impact, even though the library is compiled at the beginning if I compile my project. Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I guess I have to try it again. But if you say that this approach will work with Keil, I guess it will work with Eclipse and G++, too.

Comment: I have not tried this under Eclipse but there is no reason for it not to be possible. Conceptually It's a very simple method and I've been able to port libraries built like that between compilers in the past with very minimal changes to the actual source.

Comment: btw, IAR and Keil are actually different companies that compete with each other. but yes, this is also possible under Keil.

Comment: Thanks for all your work! Yes I have mistaken IAR and Keil. I guess I'm getting a solution that will work, I have the library now responding to defined symbols, but now the compiler complains about the function "some_driver_init" and "some_driver_start" defined twice, guess it should not be in the same folder as the header file "some_driver.h" ?

Comment: I'm guessing you included MCU specific sources in the project (e.g. some_driver_arm_m3.c). Don't do that. Instead just include the "fake" implementation (some_driver.c) at let *IT* include the right c file for your MCU.

Comment: I included 
#include "some_driver.h" in my project and added the library by -l command to the project. If I put the implementation of the function in the "some_driver.c" - file it works, if it is instead in the "some_driver_arm_m3.c" file it produces an error stating it is defined twice.

Comment: Well, I guess it's a linker problem. If I compile the library on it's own, it works. If I compile my project which includes this library the error occurs.

Comment: It works! Just some stupid mistake. You saved my day sir. That will help a lot!

Comment: No worries. Good luck!